Unable to create relationship to Address table
In my new solution, I added an existing "Address" table from the out-of-box tables. Additionally, I created my own custom "Office" table. I wanted to add a lookup field in the Office table to the Address table to establish a many-to-one relationship. However, when I tried to add this lookup column, the Related Tables dropdown list didn't give me the Address table as an option. The same issue occurred when I went to New > Relationship > Many to One screen; the Address table wouldn't show up as a dropdown list either.
What could be wrong? I noticed that when I open the Account or Contact tables, they seem to be able to form a relationship with the Address table. What am I missing?

I.m.o. the customeraddress table is one of the most disappointing parts of this "CRM" system. It consists of mainly plain text fields and it does not support sharing addresses between tables and records. Unfortunately it always has been like this.

I haven't played with the Address (customeraddress) table for awhile.
As far as I remember it's not possible to create a custom relationship (any way 1-N or N-1) with customeraddress table and there is a flag in Entity Metadata that points to this:

So, I'm afraid you won't be able to do it.
